# declaring your own session instead of session maintained by codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is there any way to define your own session instead of session maintained by codeigniter ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$_SESSION['my_session_variable'] = 'this is my session variable content';
```

You'd use session this way if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a native session variable as Thorpe showed, but using the native session library gives you a nice codeigniter-esque interface to work with sessions including flash data and so on.

http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Native_session/